# Dynamically create class property when an undefined property is referenced

Tags: php, class, oop

```php
class Table {
    public $users = 'Hello';
    public function __construct() {}
}

$table = new Table();
echo $table->users; // -> 'Hello'
echo $table->jobs; // -> PHP Warning:  Undefined property: Table::$jobs
```

The line above throws a warning as expected as I am referring to a property 'jobs' which wasn't created.

I want to have a `Table` class which connects to a database when instantiated. It should have all the table names in the database as property. Issue with this is, I do not want to create every table name manually as a property.

So, is there something like _call *(I guess)* but for properties which would allow me to have a 'middle' logic to intercept all property calls or at-least those that are not defined so then I can dynamically create a new function/class or anything from that name and return that when the property isn't defined?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Answer (score 0):

Using the __get magic method works

```php
class Table {
    public function __construct() {}

    public function __get($name) {
        // Check if the property exists in the database
        if ($this->propertyExistsInDatabase($name)) {
            // If it does, dynamically create a new function/class or anything from that name
            $this->$name = $this->createDynamicProperty($name);
            return $this->$name;
        } else {
            // If it doesn't, throw an exception or return a default value
            throw new Exception("Property '$name' does not exist in the database.");
        }
    }
}

$table = new Table();
echo $table->users; // -> 'Hello'
echo $table->jobs; // -> 'Dynamic property created from the 'jobs' table in the database'
```